# Windows 7 Ultimate x64 bit unable to save or browse files

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I have this problem where i can't open or save files. any application that saves or browse files wont save or browse files. For example, in microsoft word, if i click save as, a windows explorer would pop up as to where you are going to save the file, but for me, nothing happens. you can just repeatedly click save or save as but nothing will pop up. Same goes for opening a file, no windows explorer would pop out. not just for microsoft word, any application that has save or browse files wont work. even if i click browse files many times nothing pops out, nothing is happening.

Comment: what particular plugins? all applications cant save or browse files. a simple upload of picture using browse button doesnt work.. .exe files that requires me to browse files doesnt work either.

Comment: Could be worth repairing the system/re-install. As it is, it could be many things, this question is very broad.

Comment: Did you try a System Restore?

Answer (score -1):

Try running this command in a Command Prompt "**sfc /scannow**",
taken from this link:
[Win 7 64 bit - 3rd party apps won't open Windows dialog boxes (save as, save, open, import, etc)](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/win-7-64-bit-3rd-party-apps-wont-open-windows/5dc0192c-ea7b-452a-a5ef-db82aa24fa5e?auth=1)